# Change color of text selection tool

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to change the color of this things. **How can I do it?** (via xml or programmatically)

[image: Here]

Comment: is this programming related?

Comment: I don´t get ya.....it´s a totaly different approach. If it should be done via coding, You usually want to change it inside one of your apps. If it is not programming related, You just want to change some graphics inside Your device and then, this is not the forum for such a question.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I want to change the color of `text selection tool` inside my application. Under 'both ways' I mean: via style.xml or programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can customize theme in `res/values/style.xml`. Simply set *colorPrimary* and *colorAccent* Another way - use [this](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I got it. `text selection tool` get `colorAccent` color.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but only on API >= 21, adding this in the style:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```